# Can a trill be creaky?

Tags: pronunciation, trills

Or in other words, is it possible to pronounce [ʙ̰], [r̰], [ʀ̰], or [ʢ̰]?

I tried to pronounce these phones by myself, and I always failed. It seems the airstream from the constricted glottis cannot match the "sweet spot" to make the articulators trill.

On the other hand, pronouncing breathy trills is easy. I just need much airstream.

Yet, since my native language (Korean) doesn't have trills, I might be wrong and it might be the case that I just need practice. Is it really possible to pronounce creaky trills? If so, what languages do have them?

Comment: I can well pronounce [ʙ̰], [r̰], [ʀ̰], or at least it seems to me I can pronounce them. My native languages are Ukrainian and Russian which have the trill [r], but don't have the creaky/stiff voice feature, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @YellowSky Are you sure you didn't pronounce [ʙˤ], [rˤ], or [ʀˤ]? 'Cause I often mix up creaky voice and pharyngealization.

Comment: Yes, I am. Trills are continuous, and I seem to keep the creaky voice throughout their length. However, it's very subjective, my understanding of what ‘creaky’ is can be wrong. It's best to narrow your question just to “do any languages have creaky trills?” and exclude the part on the possibility of pronouncing them, then the subjectivity is excluded, and that's what this SE needs.

Comment: I also have no trouble pronouncing [r̰] and [ʀ̰], though I found [ʙ̰] very difficult, since a bilabial trill requires significantly stronger airflow (at least for me) and creaky voice reduces airflow. I generally have trouble reliably distinguishing pharyngeal/epiglottal fricatives and trills, so [ʢ] is tricky to me to begin with – but to the extent that I can reliably produce it at all, I actually find it _easier_ to produce with creaky voice.